# Android - Gallery with even number of images

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am using a Gallery object in my app and the size of the images is such that four seems to be the ideal number of images in the gallery at one time. Three results in too much space and five in too little.

The problem is that the gallery seems to focus on the center element and therefore I can't get the four images to fit on screen and any one time. Even if I scroll by hand as soon as the release the touch the layout adjust so that an image is in the center of the gallery.

How can I amend this ?

P.S: If the reply is "Write your own gallery..", I'd appreciate references to some pre-written galleries or sources.

Comment: Try a CloverFlow http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html

Comment: Thanks. Isn't exactly what I was looking for but seems flexible enough to be molded.

Comment: I went through the code... not quite low level enough to help... I'm marking as unanswered so that it shows up as such... no offense

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? or What function are you try execute?

Comment: Just a simple gallery which has an even number of images on a single screen.... by default, the gallery selects the one in the middle so the even, say four, images don't align properly on screen. I tried the `.setSelection()` method but that still seems to favor an odd number of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own `Gallery`. In fact, it is more of a `PaginatedGallery` similar to the one used on iPhone.

Its part of my library at : https://github.com/sfarooq/PaginatedGallery